Phase Slope Distance Calcuation
After trying to implement IFFT algorithms for phase-based ranging, as outlined in this very interesting and descriptive blog post; I've been getting horrendous results (orders of magnitude inaccurate), and this led me to go back to step one. I tried calculating a simple phase slope to get the distance, the one from the example in the blog post.

A quick estimate of the slope would give you $\frac{6\pi}{80\cdot10^{6}}$, distance would be $d=\frac{c}{4\pi}\cdot\frac{6\pi}{80\cdot10^{6}}=5.625$
Issue is, the blog post clearly outlines that ground truth distance is $9.9$ meters. Did the blog post just put the wrong diagram or am I simply implementing the steps wrong?
